# Postgresql query between time ranges on a timestamp column

Tags: postgresql, time-series, timescaledb

Assuming a table with a `timestamp` column such as

```
my_db=# \d l1
                                     Tabelle »public.l1«
    Spalte     |              Typ               | Sortierfolge | NULL erlaubt? | Vorgabewert 
---------------+--------------------------------+--------------+---------------+-------------
 timestamp     | timestamp(6) without time zone |              | not null      |
```

What is the most efficient way to query for those rows which match

```
<stub>
time(timestamp)>='10:00:00' and time(timestamp)<='10:30:00'
</stub>
```

I could not find a suitable [BETWEEN](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-between/) statement.

Comment: Hi gies0r Does Postgres's tsrange help? Ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/48117316/1123335

Comment: @pnorton It does not look like this is suitable.. From the docs:  **tsrange — Range of timestamp without time zone**. This is not what I search for (because this filters between two datetime-fields). What I am looking for is a range filter, which ignores the date-part of the timestamp column and only filters for the time of day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficiency of your query will rather depend on your data volume and indexing technique. That being said, you can simply cast the column `timestamp` to `time` and use a between as you suggested:

```
SELECT * FROM l1
WHERE CAST(timestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '13:00:00';
```

or if you don't need to stick to SQL Ansi (imho a much cooler notation) ..

```
SELECT * FROM l1
WHERE timestamp::TIME BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '13:00:00';
```