# Select month between 2 date in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, generate-series

For example I have a report that requires February have column `Created_date` start at `2022-01-26` and end at `2022-02-25`

How would I set up a query such that I retrieve the following table as a response:

```
            **Month of the year**

Feb (((Description: Start from 2021/01/26 to 2022/02/25)))

Mar (((Description: Start from 2021/02/26 to 2022/03/25)))

Apr (((Description: Start from 2021/03/26 to 2022/04/25)))

May (((Description: Start from 2021/04/26 to 2022/05/25)))
```

I put the description to easy understand, i dont need it in the table.

BTW I'm too fussed about the format, anything that works will do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql query between date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335970/postgresql-query-between-date-ranges)

Comment: No, because I need it automatic for everymonth to put it on my dashboard.

Comment: So you want 4 rows with three columns? (Name of the Month, start date, end date)

Comment: No, I need only 1 column for the month. Is there any query that can put 4 rows with one column?

Comment: BTW I'm too fussed about the format, anything that works will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generates four rows with three columns:

```
select to_char(dt, 'Mon') as month,
       dt::date as start_day,
       (dt::date + interval '1 month')::date as end_day
from generate_series(date '2021-01-26', 
                     date '2021-04-26', interval '1 month') as g(dt)
```

If you want this as a single column, then just format and concatenate the values:

```
select to_char(dt, 'Mon')||' (((Description: Start from '||
       to_char(dt, 'yyyy/mm/dd')||' to '||
       to_char((dt::date + interval '1 month'), 'yyyy/mm/dd')||')))'
from generate_series(date '2021-01-26', 
                     date '2021-04-26', interval '1 month') as g(dt)
```

Comment: Ok, it's working. But for example: If i want to count `user_id` in tbl kyc. How can i do it with that query.